# Is it possible to nullify dagger application component and create a new dagger application component in android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a feature where I need to have different Room Databases for different users.
I am using Dagger 2 for creating Room Database. My Application Component creates one room database. When user switches to another user I want to create new Room Database for that I would need new Application component to be created. I am able to do that but the old one will still exist. How can I destroy the old Application Component and Create new Application Component.

I am defining Application Component in Application class as shown below:

```
var daggerComponent: ApplicationComponent? = null
 daggerComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(this).build()
 ApplicationInjector.init(this) { application ->
 daggerComponent?.inject(application)
}
```

When switching users I am trying to do this:

```
val appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(application = application).build()
ApplicationInjector.init(propertyManagerApplication) { application ->
appComponent?.inject(application)
}
```

How can I destroy the old component completely and then create a new component so that only one component exists at a point of time

Answer (score 2):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle.

You should have your Room database in a component with a different scope than the `ApplicationComponent` has. Then you could be rebuilding this component easily, anytime and all dependencies that relate strictly to User session would be separated.

---

E.g. (writing off the top of my head, so **not** tested)

1. Create a custom `Scope`

```
@Scope
@Retention(value = AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class UserSessionScope
```

1. Create a `Subcomponent` (use the created `Scope`):

```
@UserSessionScope
@Subcomponent
interface UserSessionComponent {

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(): UserSessionComponent
    }

    // INITIALIZE YOUR ROOM DATABASE
    // AND ALL DEPENDENCIES THAT DEPEND ON THE ROOM DATABASE

    // inject functions, etc.
}
```

2. A new module to notify Dagger of subcomponents:

```
@Module(subcomponents = UserSessionComponent::class)
class SubcomponentsModule {}
```

3. In your `ApplicationComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [SubcomponentsModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    
    fun userSessionComponent(): UserSessionComponent.Factory
 
}
```

4. Maintain the `UserSessionComponent` in your `Application` as long as the user session is maintained (user is not switched).

```
class YourApplication : Application() {

    lateinit var appComponent : ApplicationComponent
    lateinit var userSessionComponent : UserSessionComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        //...
        initAppComponent();
        createUserSession();
    }

    private fun initAppComponent() {
         appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    }

    fun createUserSession() {
        userSessionComponent = appComponent.userSessionComponent().create()
    }
}
```

---

Now all your `Application` scoped dependencies will be held within `ApplicationComponent` and maintained as long as the `Application` is alive.
`UserSessionComponent` will maintain all dependencies that have a shorter lifespan (exist as long as the User session is valid).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this.

Comment: I tried this approach but my other modules are linked to RoomModule so I will have to move all modules to sub component will that cause any issues?

Comment: If they are linked to your room module then they depend on the user session. This is a valid observation from the dagger itself. When your database changes, related dependencies should be rebuilt as well.